# Stopping nginx to 30(2|1) redirect for /.well-known location

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I'm setting up letsencrypt for two different domains: example.be and example.com

I've got Nginx configured to redirect all example.com/* requests to example.be/de/*

```
// Block 1
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .example.com;
    return 302 http://example.be/de$request_uri;
}

// Block 2
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.be;
    return 302 http://example.be$request_uri;
}

Block 3
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.be;

    // server config
}
```

Eventually everything should land on Block 3. Except for the .well-known requests letsencrypt makes to `.example.com`
*The 302's are there temporary; after everything works they go to 301.*

So I thought of 'catching' that uri in the first server block.

```
// rewrite of Block 1
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name .example.com;

   location ^~ /.well-known/ {
     root        /path/to/public/folder/;
     try_files   $uri =404;
   }

  return 302 http://example.be/de$request_uri;
}
```

A request to `http://example.com/.well-known/test.html` results in a redirect to `http://example.be/de/.well-known/test.html`

If I remove the return statement, the `test.html` page is displayed.

Any pointers in how to catch this request for .well-known directory?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you've used `^~` in your `location`. It's not necessary. Try removing it.

My working certbot configuration is:

```
server {
        server_name www.yes-www.org yes-www.org www.yes-www.com yes-www.com;

        listen [::]:80;
        listen 80;

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }

        access_log off;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

If that doesn't work, try removing everything else from your `server` block that is present but that you might not have posted in your question.